# Why does sqlcmd give a connection timeout but not SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

On my dev workstation, I'm connecting to a SQL Server 2012 database with SSMS, using the server name `server,port` -and it works perfectly.

However, on the same dev workstation, when I'm trying to connect to the same SQL Server, I get a connection timeout when using `sqlcmd`. The command line would be

```
sqlcmd -S server,port -E
```

Any idea why it works with SSMS but not with `sqlcmd`?

Comment: -S has an optional protocol component. Have you tried each one? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

Comment: Yes I tried all of them